# How to disable evil-mode everywhere?

Tags: evil

I have recently installed emacs doom, and I tried to customise it with some custom keybindings. I have found that Evil is just not something I want. I can disable it on a per-buffer basis with `M-x turn-off-evil-mode`, but I do not want to have to type that command everytime I open a file

How can I disable evil mode everywhere? I don't want it.

PS: The Emacs doom documentation apparently used to explain how to this, but the link points to nowhere

Comment: The correct way to disable it interactively is `M-x evil-mode` as it's a global minor mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

More explanations how to remove Evil are in `.emacs.d/modules/editor/evil/README.org` and to quote it:

> You must do two things to remove Evil:
>
> 1. Remove `:editor evil` from `~/.doom.d/init.el`,
> 2. Run *doom refresh* to clean up lingering dependencies and refresh your    autoloads files.
> 3. [OPTIONAL] You may want to assign new values to `doom-leader-alt-key` and    `doom-localleader-alt-key`. These are
>    bound to `C-c` and `C-c l` by default.

Read also all text there, you must make effort to implement Emacs keybinding everywhere.

One word of caution - in time normal Emacs keybindings will induce some pain for your fingers (as for me also) and a normal way to avoid such is to use Evil mode, since `C- ...` commands are replaced by some others keybindings not using your left thumb.

Edit: *doom refresh* was replaced by *doom sync* in newest updates.

Comment: I have been using emacs for some 25 years and do not have pain in my fingers.

It is true that I once did, but I haven't for quite a while (15 years?).  Maybe the thing that did it was when I moved the [Ctrl key to the home-row](https://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/answers/Hardware/Getting_Control_on_Caps_Lock_A_How_To) where God Intended as it was on my [Sun Type 6 keyboard](http://xahlee.info/kbd/sun_microsystems_keyboard.html) and or the [IBM XT keyboard](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/IBM_Model_F_XT.png).

Comment: ```doom refresh``` is now ```doom sync```. I also disagree about the finger pain, never had any :)

Comment: Not all people are the same. I have that pain; some others also complain about.

Comment: You use your left thumb on the control key? How?