# From stock Emacs to Emacs Doom - Issues with Key Bindings and de-activating Evil-mode - ORG-MODE use

Tags: init-file, evil, doom

I have migrated to emacs-Doom and wish to keep the emacs vanilla key-bindings. I also use emacs exclusively for org-mode

I have amended the init.el file to remove the evil and removed any attributes that call evil-mode.

I still am having issues with evil-mode being activated. C-z works for me on some occasions, not others.

Is there any comprehensive docs that deal with this issue? I have researched the various emacs-doom docs and specific docs on evil-mode, but I cannot seem to wipe out evil mode entirely.

Ultimately what I am seeking is use of emacs-doom without evil-mode for org-mode use only.

Comment: Maybe this https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53319/how-to-disable-evil-mode-everywhere/53320#53320 will be what you look for?

Comment: What's the question? Are you really asking for doc? Not too clear. "I'm having issues" isn't very focused.

Comment: thanks guys, I have elected to remove doom emacs entirely and do a fresh install of stock emacs

Comment: Have you followed the "Removing evil-mode` section of https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/develop/modules/editor/evil/README.org? In particular have you run `doom sync`.